# remove observer in dealloc with an object

Tags: ios, objective-c

i've an object declared as:

```
AVQueuePlayer *queuePlayer;
```

in code i've added an observer:

```
- (void) playStreamedTrack: (Track *) track {

[queuePlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];

        [queuePlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, NSEC_PER_SEC)
                                                  queue:nil
                                             usingBlock:^(CMTime time) {
                                                 progress = time.value/time.timescale;
                                             }];
}
```

i've tried to remove the observer as follow, but not work

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

    [queuePlayer removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" context:nil];
}
```

how can i remove the observer?

Comment: Is `dealloc` being called?

Comment: yes, dealloc methiod i use is above. 
 
ther error in console is:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x7f970b55ae00 of class AVQueuePlayer was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7f970d974c10> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f970d991910: Observer: 0x7f970d9b50c0, Key path: status, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7f970b6fb390>
)'

Comment: How many times is the observer registered?  It looks to me like it's being registered in the wrong place if that "track" is played more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by `[AVPlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval]` doc, you must retain the return value in order to be able to remove the observer later on.

So you need to add a property in your class interface

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id playerObserver;
```

And store the returned value when you create the observer

```
if(self.playerObserver)
    [queuePlayer removeTimeObserver:self.playerObserver];
self.playerObserver = [self.queuePlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, NSEC_PER_SEC)
                                                                     queue:nil
                                                                usingBlock:^(CMTime time) {
                                                                    progress = time.value/time.timescale;
                                                                }];
```

In the dealloc, you can then release the observer

```
- (void)dealloc {    
    [queuePlayer removeTimeObserver:self.playerObserver];
    [queuePlayer removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" context:nil];
}
```

Please, also note that in your block, you might need to use weak reference to your instance in order to avoid retain cycle. If your "progress" variable is actually an instance variable, you must use a weak reference like this one :

```
__typeof__(self) __weak weakSelf = self;

self.playerObserver = [self.queuePlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, NSEC_PER_SEC)
                                                                     queue:nil
                                                                usingBlock:^(CMTime time) {
                                                                    weakSelf.progress = time.value/time.timescale;
                                                                }];
```

Comment: done but still: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x7fac9d0b0ba0 of class AVQueuePlayer was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7fac9af06650> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7fac9af5ae20: Observer: 0x7fac9d08c320, Key path: status, Options: <New: NO, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7fac9eddda30>

Comment: I've edited my answer to remove the previous observer before adding a new one (if there is any). This might be why you still have a registered observer.

Comment: Phil thanks so much, It's strange now it show this:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An instance of AVPlayer cannot remove a time observer that was added by a different instance of AVPlayer.'

Comment: You certainly create a new AVPlayer each time, then before creating it, you should remove its observer. Just move the removeTimeObserver before the AVPlayer creation ant this should do the trick.

Comment: Phil it Works Great!!! i've moved 
[queuePlayer  removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" context:nil];
to a - (void) resetStreamPlayer method called when i start a new song!!
Thanks very much!!! :D